# dynamic title size using titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, width

Is there a way to dynamically size titles as part of a `\titleformat` (from the `titlesec` package) definition? I'd like to scale titles of different lengths to be the same width (relative to `\textwidth`) by only changing fontsize.

The answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132039/dynamic-font-size-for-hbox) describe how to resize text in a similar way, but I'm not sure how this could be used to redefine/extend the section titles. (e.g. as a part of `\titleformat*{\subsection}` ...)

Comment: Did you try to use `\resizebox`?

Comment: @Sigur not sucessfully. how would it work?

Comment: For instance, you'd want that `\section{Abc}` and `\section{Abc def ghi jkl}` typeset the text filling the same width?

Comment: @egreg. correct.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @egreg. regardless of the merit of the idea, can you see how it would be possible?  (most of the section titles are of similar but not the same length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like a good idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,graphicx}

\titleformat{\section}
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {\thesection}
 {1em}
 {\resizetitle}

\newcommand{\resizetitle}[1]{\resizebox{\sectionwidth}{!}{#1}}
\newlength{\sectionwidth}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\sectionwidth}{.3\textwidth}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Abc}

\section{Def ghi klm}

\section{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}

\end{document}
```

[image]

One could scale also the numbers, but the overall result doesn't seem worthy a try.

Comment: thanks for providing an answer, despite your reservations. it works as expected.